# PHP character whitelist validation WITHOUT preg_replace or regex

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-replace, whitelist

I am writing a simple field reporting web app that only accepts a small number of characters.

I have read that preg_replace has a negative affect on performance.

This is a problem because I want to loop through all **$_POST** and **$_GET** variables to sanitize them and some of my forms have many fields.

Is there a faster way to whitelist?

for example:

```
if(isset($_GET["test_1"]) && isset($_GET["test_2"])){
$white_list = str_split('0123456789
                       abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,?@_-'); 
foreach($_GET as $key => &$val){
    $val = array_intersect(str_split($val),$white_list);
    $val = implode($val);
}
}
```

You can see that I am only allowing a few characters for punctuation.

The space character seems to work when I test in the URL bar.

I have also seen people use str_replace() after splitting the input into an array and replacing characters with "" if they are not in the whitelist.

```
if(isset($_GET["test_1"]) && isset($_GET["test_2"])){
$white_list = str_split('0123456789
                       abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                       ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,?@_-'); 
foreach($_GET as $key => &$val){
    $char_list = str_split($val);
    foreach($char_list as $c){
        if(!in_array($c,$white_list)){
            $val = str_replace($c,'',$val);
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Or something like that.

Are there performance gains to be had?

How would I test it.

Comment: All this is to improve the performance of the 0.002%? But I think that in that way you do even worsen.

Comment: Wait wait... did you measure the performance? Do you really think some PHP script will perform better than optimized C code? The rule of thumb in scripting languages is to leverage built-in functions, as they most probably *will* be faster than anything you can come up with. Also, how many simultaneous connections do you expect? Is performance an issue in the first place? If it is, dropping PHP altogether is your best bet.